# MEAN stack how to handle login and redirect

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I have a simple MEAN stack application, just try to learn about authentication and get it to work.

You can checkout the complete program in github: https://github.com/7seven7lst/chatterApp

I have the following in Angular (app.js) with profile route been restricted:

```
angular.module('chat', ['ui.router', 'chat.main', 'chat.signin', 'chat.profile'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('signin', {
            url: '/signin',
            templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
            controller: 'SigninCtrl'
        })
        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile', 
            templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
        });

    // the following will give angular injection error
    /*
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $state) {
      return {
        response: function(response) {
          // do something on success
          return response;
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            $state.go('home');
          } 
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    });
    */

});
```

And I have NodeJS function to handle authentication:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// setup passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done){
    if (username !== 'test' || password !='password'){
      console.log("not loged in ");
      return done(null, false); // login failed
    } else {
      console.log("somehow we are here");
      return done(null, {username: username});
    }
  }

));



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user);
})

// middleware function to handle protected route
var requireAuthentication = function(req, res, next){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    next();
  } else {
    console.log("401 should be sent here...");
    res.end(401);
    //res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // middleware to parse the form data
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // server static file in public folder. 
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); 
app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(session({
  secrete: 'make this a good secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log("here, homepage");
  res.sendFile('index.html');
})


app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/profile', failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res){
  res.send(req.user);
});


app.get('/profile', [requireAuthentication,
function(req, res){
  console.log("here, profile page");
  res.json(200, {username: req.session.passport.user.username});
}])

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log("listening on port 8080");
})
```

I tested my app and no 401 is ever sent from server. And the angular interceptor doesn't seem to work if I try to uncomment the above lines. 
How can I get the protected route working in anuglar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at repository code it looks like your form in `signin.html` is trying to call a `signin` function on submit. This function is not defined so no request is being sent to the server, hence no response.

edit:

There are two separate considerations when dealing with authentication for your MEAN application. The authentication done on the server and on the client.

**Server**

On the server, for routes you have used the `requireAuthentication` middleware the client will be sent 401 status code responses if the user has not authenticated.

In your browser if you type in `localhost:8080/profile` you will get a 401 response from the server.

**Client**

On the client because you have not specified you want to use [html5mode](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag). The client side routing is done using the fragment url (the part of the url that starts with `#`). That part of the url is not sent to the server. If you make a request to `localhost:8080/#/profile` the path the server gets in the http request is `/`.

That `/` route is configured on the server to respond with the `index.html` file in your case. The `index.html` then makes the requests to load the angular scripts and runs your client code.

At this point `ui.router` will handle the client side routing. This is where you need to do authentications checks on the client. There are several strategies for indicating a state requires authentication.

One such way is putting a tag on the actual state definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',         // is actually /#/
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
...
  .state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',  // is actually /#/profile
    templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    authRequired: true
  });
```

Then adding a run block that adds a listen on the rootscope for `stateChangeStart` events:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, nextState, params) {
    if (nextState.authRequired && !Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      $state.go('signin');
    }
  });
});
```

The auth service will need to know if a user is authenticated which might require a server roundtrip the first time. There are tons of answers on stackoverflow regarding how to do that.

---

The other part is the in `$httpProvider.interceptors` part. From your angular client, if you make a request to the server to a route that requires authentication, in your example `/profile` (not `/#/profile`, remember that is just `/`), and you are not authenticated, you will get a `401` response. The auth interceptor part tells the angular client how to respond in that situation.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $injector) {

...

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
      responseError: function(response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          $injector.get('$state').go('signin');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  });
});
```